# How do I get LaunchBar to open the enclosing folder for a selected file?

Tags: finder, launchbar

After selecting a file or application in LaunchBar, how do I get it to show it in the Finder? (I'd like the equivalent of right-clicking on a file in a Spotlight search and selecting "Open Enclosing Folder" in the pop-up menu.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command-Return

Hold the Command key and tap the Return key

This will bring you to a Finder window, where the file/app is selected within the enclosing folder.